# "trust" issues in pg_hba.conf

Tags: php, postgresql, md5

I teach an undergraduate database curriculum at my local large university (LLU).  We use the Google Cloud Platform and have been using Ubuntu Pro 20.04 with PostgreSQL 12, pgAdmin, and php 7.3 and everything is bippidy-boo!

I did a generic, clean installation of an upgrade test to Ubuntu 22.04 and it all worked until I came to testing pg_connect(***).  No matter what I did, it failed.  I briefly considered starting drinking; however, instead, I read my PostgreSQL logs, and, therein, I found:

```
2023-03-23 17:54:35.235 UTC [4778] sws****@sws**** FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "sws****"
2023-03-23 17:54:35.235 UTC [4778] sws****@sws**** DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 93: "host    all                   all     0.0.0.0/0       md5"
```

So, I changed line 93 of my pg_hba.conf from "md5" to "trust" and, just like magic, it connected!  Obviously, that's
*a* fix and might work on sandboxed machines such as we have; however, it is certainly a poor way to train budding
DB admins!

Something is responsible for doing the password encryption!

In the postgresql.conf I see

```
# - Authentication -
#password_encryption = scram-sha-256    # scram-sha-256 or md5
```

I have been playing with that to little or no avail.  I would think that pg_connect would do the encryption
using something like crypt().

Anyone have any clues to my immediate whereabouts they could share?

I tracked the issue to the "md5" vs "trust" in the pg_hba.conf file.  pg_connect is doing it's think, but the passwords aren't encrypted or may not even be used at all.  I expect to be able to return to md5 encryption.

Comment: If the password is stored in SCRAM format, then the authentication will be done in SCRAM, not md5.  The simplest explanation here is that your password is wrong.

Comment: 1) After the upgrade are you still using Postgres 12 or a newer version? 2) As a superuser, say postgres, what is the prefix for the entries in the `passwd` field when you do `select * from pg_shadow;`

Comment: HOLY COW, BATMAN!  IT'S SCRAM-SHA-256!!!

(I wonder what that's trying to tell me?)

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks.  (Give yerself a "kill".)

Comment: 1) You still did not answer what version of Postgres you are using in the new install of Ubuntu 22.04 2) Also how did you move the data from the old install of Postgres to the new/ 3) Per [pg_hba.conf passwoed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-password.html): *To ease transition from the md5 method to the newer SCRAM method, if md5 is specified as a method in pg_hba.conf but the user's password on the server is encrypted for SCRAM (see below), then SCRAM-based authentication will automatically be chosen instead*

Comment: If one takes the default version of PGSQL on Ubuntu 22.04, I believe one gets version 14.  I didn't move any data; as a professor, I have the luxury of nuking everything and starting over every semester.

I'll give you any further information you want... but, may I ask why you need it?  You resolved my question.